# How to force operator>>(C<T>) overload to match container?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, containers, extraction-operator

I would like to have `operator>>()` overloads for any "base" type and for any container type. This is what I have so far:

```
typedef uintmax_t my_t;
template <typename T>
std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &iss, T &v)
{
    static my_t um = 6009;
    v = um++;
    return iss;
}

template <template <class> class C, typename T>
std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &iss, C<T> &c)
{
    for (typename C<T>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
        iss >> *it;
    return iss;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint32_t> vi(3);
    std::istringstream iss;
    iss >> vi;
    for (std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator it = vi.begin(); it != vi.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles and runs as expected with GCC but does not even compile on VS2015. The latter matches the `>>` operator in the `iss >> vi;` statement with the first, base-type overload, which triggers other compilation errors. How can I write an `operator>>()` template for non-container types and a template for container types (without having to specialize for each container type) that compiles with GCC and VS2015?

Comment: This shouldn't compile anywhere. Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: Interesting.. I can't get this to compile on g++ 5.1.0 - how did you get it to compile on your version of gcc?

Comment: Here it is on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/juUAvEP6). They say that it's [g++ 4.1.2](http://codepad.org/about).

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question , but, have you considered updating your compiler?

Comment: I just use codepad.org because it's handy. Also, I want a C++98 solution.

Comment: @Alejandro, I just read that the C++98 flag in g++, really selects C++03, probably to get the 03 bug fixes in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator>>` overload you wrote is for a template template class (`C`) with a single template argument (`T`). However, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is declared as:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

The second template argument may be defaulted, but it is still there. As such, `std::vector<uint32_t>` cannot match `C<T>` - so the only viable overload is the generic function template that you wrote, which won't compile because you can't assign a `std::uintmax_t` to a `vector`.

In order to get your function to accept `vector`, you need to match the template template declaration - which means, take a second type argument:

```
template <template <class, class> class C, typename T1, typename T2>
std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &iss, C<T1,T2> &c)
{
    for (typename C<T1,T2>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
        iss >> *it;
    return iss;
}
```

This is a pretty unsatisfactory solution though. Really, we want to match on anything that is a container, which we can do using SFINAE. Since this is C++03, the simplest thing would be to write a type trait for whether or not some type has a typedef named `iterator`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_container {
    typedef char yes;

    struct no {
        char _[2];
    };

    template <typename U>
    static yes test( typename U::iterator* );

    template <typename U>
    static no test(...);

    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes));
};
```

And add our handy `enable_if`:

```
template <bool, typename >
struct enable_if { };

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { 
    typedef T type;
};
```

And stick that on the return type:

```
template <typename C>
typename enable_if<
    is_container<C>::value,
    std::istringstream&
>::type
operator>>(std::istringstream &iss, C& c)
{
    for (typename C::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
        iss >> *it;
    return iss;
}
```

You'll have to do the opposite (`!is_container<T>::value`) for the other overload so that they're not ambiguous.

Comment: Barry, impressive, but I get the same results--works with g++ but not with VS2015. Here it is on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/d0A5RtVo).

Comment: @Barry There seems to be a problem. If you define both "container" and "non-container" overloads, then `iss >> *it;` in the "container" overload will use the "non-container" `operator>>`, not the default version, right?

Comment: @SU3, that's what I want it to do--use my non-container overload--and that's what g++ 4,1,2 does; however, VS2015 tries to use my non-container overload for the `iss >> vi;` in my main(). But `vi` is a container.It's looking like there isn't an elegant solution to this. :-/

Comment: @Barry, I take that back--it _does_ work. VS2015 just wanted a `static_cast<C>()` around `um++` in my "base" overload. I gotta let your solution sink in, though. I would have a single overload for all containers, but at the cost of all that supporting code.

Comment: It should be possible to avoid the trait. Dispatch to a pair of overloaded helpers, one taking a `typename T::iterator*` and the other taking `...`.

Comment: I ended up using is_container<> and enable_if_c<> from Boost.

Comment: @T.C. HA. First time I read your comment, I thought the `...` were a "fill in the blank here" and not "literally use ellipses." Yeah, that would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @user4438540 Sure, Boost has lots of very useful things in it :)